# confusion on force = mass x acceleration

Tags: physics

this doesnt even make sense

if force = mass x acceleration

then thats like saying a car that weighs 2000 kg traveling at 80 mph and not accelerating will hit you and there will be no force but i would definitely get run over???? **(no)**

how does this even make sense?

is it only one way, like hitting a car with 50000 m/s^2 of force would make it go 25 mph or whatever? **(yes)**

note, i understand that pounds is a conversion from newtons (which represents gravitational force = weight), so the numbers aren't exact, but this is more conceptual

thanks, i just need a yes or no, because i can't seem to find one online :)

Comment: The force part engages when the car hits you and your body undergoes the acceleration from stopped to near the car's starting speed...

Comment: In essence, conserving the total momentum of both bodies.

Comment: 1 newton of force is the force required to accelerate an object with a mass of 1 kilogram 1 meter per second per second.

Comment: "50000 m/s^2 of force" that is a unit of acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acceleration in $F=ma$ is the acceleration **caused** by the force -- not the acceleration of the object *causing* the force -- and especially not *before it even exerts the force*.  So if a car hits you, you'd be accelerated backward from whatever your initial speed is to the same speed that the car is going -- that's the acceleration that $a$ represents.

---

It might be better to remember the formula in the form that Newton originally expressed it, though (updated with modern notation, of course): $$F = \frac{dp}{dt}$$ This tells us that the force is equal in magnitude to the rate of change of momentum of the object the force is exerted upon.  Let's say that you have a mass of 70 kg and you're standing still when the car hits you.  Then your initial momentum is $0$ kg m/s.  The car hits you and in the course of say 0.2 seconds your speed increases to 20 m/s.  So your final momentum is $70\cdot 20 = 1400$ kg m/s.  Then the force exerted on you is far from 0 N.  It is (approximately) $$F\approx \frac{1400-0}{0.2} = 7000\ \text{N}$$

Comment: OH! That makes so much more sense